# Linq query to SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I have a Linq Query that works well but I need to write the SQL Query 
Can Anybody help me write it?
this query will search the database `foreach` `a.h` and `a.HV` in the `view` with the filters of time and model and in the end it checks the option `Filter.M` that if it is selected it will search for all the data selected in this DropDownCheckBoxes`
How can i write the this where and select part in SQL command?

```
ret1 = (from a in View
        where
            a.LastRefreshTime>=Filter.From && a.LastRefreshTime<=Filter.To && a.ModelCode == mdlCode &&
            Filter.PN.Select(epn => epn.Substring(0, 11)).Contains(a.H) &&
            Filter.PN.Select(epn => epn.Substring(14, 2)).Contains(a.HV)

        select new RData
        {
            v = a.v,
            Date = a.LastRefreshTime,
            UserId = a.UserId,
            M = a.Name,
        }).Distinct().AsQueryable();
ret = ret1.Where(nr =>
    Filter.M == null || !Filter.M.Any() || Filter.M.Contains(nr.M)
).ToList();
```

Comment: it is working but for some reason I should write the sql query, I just updated my quetion

Comment: Yes, but what *SQL* have you written already and in what way does *that* not work?

Comment: i need to know how to write this query, the part 'contains' in sql

Comment: Linq pad can translate from one to the other, not sure how reliable it is as I haven't used it for anything meaningful. http://www.linqpad.net/. doing contains in sql you should look at this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: Just execute it with the SQL profiler running and there it is...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start for you

```
select a.v v,
       a.LastRefreshTime "Date",
       a.UserId,
       a.Name
  from a
 where a.LastRefreshTime>= arg_filter_from
   and a.LastRefreshTime<= arg_filter_to
   and a.ModelCode = arg_mdlCode
   .
   .
   .
```

In this query you'll need to replace 'arg_...' with the appropriate values or arguments you want.

**Contains** is roughly equivalent to **"IN"** in SQL.  For example:

```
where a.Name in ('jim', 'bob', 'joe')
```

In can also be used with a subselect which is roughly what I think Filter.PN.Select is doing though I'm not a linq expert.  Example:

```
where a.H in (Select foo from PN_Table)
```

Or simpler example continuing on the my previous name example:

```
where a.Name in (select first_name from table)
```

Answer (score 0):

If we supposed that the Filter.PN list represent a table FilterPN in your sql database, that will be your converted code for the first linq query

1. `select distinct a.v, a.LastRefreshTime, a.UserId, a.Name

    from [view] a 
    where a.LastRefreshTime>= 'Filter.From' and

       a.LastRefreshTime<='Filter.To' and a.ModelCode = 'mdlCode' and

       exists(select top 1 * from FilterPN where Substring(epn, 1, 11) = a.H) and 
       exists(select top 1 * from FilterPN where Substring(e`enter code here`pn, 15, 2) = a.HV)`

think to replace the enquoted variables with ur real values 'Filter.To'...

Comment: Thanks. I want to know tha, this query return many rows and I have a class  like public class RData
    {
        public string V;
       ...
        public string D;
    }
in Select part I need to read them And put them into this class

Comment: and the other peoblem is that my Filter data is the data in a dropdownboax. so xcan I write it like sql query?